# Database design for apple pass coupons

Tags: mysql, database

I'm working on project which requires apple pass integration. I designed my database tables as the following:

device table

`id | device_id | push_token | created_at | updated_at`

passes table

`id | pass_type_id | serial_number | auth_token | created_at | updated_at`

device_pass_registration tabel (for registering a device for apple pass)

`id | device | pass_id | created_at | updated_at`

coupons table

`id | user_name | ... | pass_id | created_at | updated_at`

I have another 10 fields in coupons table

Can I add a JOSN field in `coupons` table and put all my coupons data in it? would that be a problem later.

There will only one pass per coupon and there can be more than 6000 coupons we will create per day. I'm concerned about the server load.

Also there is dashboard for reporting purpose.

Thanks,
Unnikrishnan B.

Comment: That depends on the relation between the coupons and the passes. If there can be more than one coupon per pass, the use the normalized design in your question.

Comment: @SloanThrasher - There will only one coupon per pass.

Comment: From my personal experience with the MySQL JSON functions I would definitely not recommend using them. While there's only one piece of data in them they are easy to manipulate but as soon as there are more I almost always find it would be easier to have the data in separate columns in the table.

Comment: @Nick - If it's a JSON it's easy for me to create pass file from it, otherwise I need to compile it to a JSON structure.

Comment: I understand and that is obviously a factor in the design. And as long as you only have one variable in the JSON you should be fine.

Comment: @Nick - Not just one variable around 10 variables also some Arabic field values but not complicated.

Comment: Just so long as you don't want to extract data from the JSON in MySQL or search on it (i.e. use it in a WHERE) you should be fine.

Comment: I developed in the past a system that would need to deal with quite complex JSONs within Stored Procedures (and also in MySQL). In my case, the number of elements within the JSON could range  from 1 to, say, few hundreds. I didn't face any performance issues and, according to your estimation of more than 6000 JSON processes/day, the question is **WHAT IS MORE THAN 6000**? Is it **UP TO 10000**? **10000000000**? JSON scanning would not take more than a fraction of a second, and you have 86,400 seconds/day.

Comment: @FDavidov - Yes I'm also thinking the same but people don't like JSON in relational databases they says it's against normalisation etc etc.

Comment: Well, Oracle (for instance) enables to define a table where one of the columns is a table in itself (i.e. a table within a table). That would serve your needs, except that MySQL does not support that, so, you sometimes need to make use of some tricks. As per "normalization", that's a very wide word. Finally, and as always, you can make use of anything the platform allows you **AS LONG AS** your are very careful, you properly document your code (so others as well as yourself can understand it), and perform extensive tests. If you comply with those, you should not be afraid. Good luck!!!